# Vue.js methods not working when input changed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I write two inputs by same change function in Vue but when inputs changed, `birthday_changed` method works just on one input. What should I do to resolve this problem ?

```html
<select v-model="client.day" id="birthday_day">
     <option v-for="day in 31" :key=day :value="('0' + day).slice(-2)">{{ ("0" + day).slice(-2) }}</option>
</select>

<select v-model="client.year" @change="birthday_changed" id="birthday_year">
    <option v-for="year in 81" :key=year :value="1320 + year"> {{ 1320 + year }} </option>
</select>

birthday_changed: function () {
    alert('changed');
},
```

Comment: what you mean , you have used onchange event in second select only

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue.js change method not working on two inputs change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74303023/vue-js-change-method-not-working-on-two-inputs-change)

Comment: looks like it was caused by a missing @change event in the first select

Answer (score 0):

Just add your onchange `@change` event to the first select.

```
<select v-model="client.day" id="birthday_day" @change="birthday_changed" >
 <option v-for="day in 31" :key=day :value="('0' + day).slice(-2)">{{ ("0" + day).slice(-2) }}</option>
</select>
```

```js
const { createApp } = Vue;
const App = {  
  data() {
    return {
      client: { day: 1, year: 1}
    }
  },
  methods: {   
     birthday_changed: function () {
        alert('changed: ' + JSON.stringify(this.client));
    },
  }
};

createApp(App).mount("#app");
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="client.day" @change="birthday_changed" id="birthday_day">
     <option v-for="day in 31" :key=day :value="('0' + day).slice(-2)">
       {{ ("0" + day).slice(-2) }}
     </option>
   </select>
  <select v-model="client.year" @change="birthday_changed" id="birthday_year">
      <option v-for="year in 81" :key=year :value="1320 + year"> {{ 1320 + year }} </option>
  </select>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```