# Vue.js change method not working on two inputs change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

0

I write two inputs by same change function in vue.js but when inputs changed T method works just on one input. what should i do tp resolve this problem?

```
<select v-model="client.day" @change="birthday_changed" id="birthday_day">
     <option v-for="day in 31" :key=day :value="('0' + day).slice(-2)">{{ ("0" + day).slice(-2) }}</option>
</select>

<select v-model="client.year" @change="birthday_changed" id="birthday_year">
    <option v-for="year in 81" :key=year :value="1320 + year"> {{ 1320 + year }} </option>
</select>



birthday_changed: function () {
    alert('changed');
},
```

Comment: Hi, please do **not** multi-post the exact same questions.

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected which works on both input. You may check the other code.

```js
const { createApp } = Vue;

createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      client: {
        day: '',
        year: ''
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    birthday_changed() {
      alert('changed');
    },
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<main id="app">
  
  <select
    v-model="client.day"
    @change="birthday_changed"
    id="birthday_day">
    <option
      v-for="day in 31"
      :key=day :value="('0' + day).slice(-2)">
      {{ ("0" + day).slice(-2) }}
    </option>
  </select>

  <select
    v-model="client.year"
    @change="birthday_changed" 
    id="birthday_year">
    <option
      v-for="year in 81"
      :key=year
      :value="1320 + year">
      {{ 1320 + year }}
    </option>
  </select>
</main>
```

Comment: Sorry, I closed this question since it's a duplicate. You may post your answer on the other post if you'd like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74302894/vue-js-methods-not-working-when-input-changed

Comment: @kissu sure, I just flagged this question as a duplicate, thanks a lot for what you've done for the community

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well.

```js
const { createApp } = Vue;
const App = {  
  data() {
    return {
      client: { day: 1, year: 1}
    }
  },
  methods: {   
     birthday_changed: function () {
        alert('changed: ' + JSON.stringify(this.client));
    },
  }
};

createApp(App).mount("#app");
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="client.day" @change="birthday_changed" id="birthday_day">
     <option v-for="day in 31" :key=day :value="('0' + day).slice(-2)">
       {{ ("0" + day).slice(-2) }}
     </option>
   </select>
  <select v-model="client.year" @change="birthday_changed" id="birthday_year">
      <option v-for="year in 81" :key=year :value="1320 + year"> {{ 1320 + year }} </option>
  </select>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```